# Can someone explain how Python's subprocess module communicates with Command Prompt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, command-prompt

I am very new to programming and have been pouring over this site and others to better understand how I can write a script in Python (version 3.4.1) that does what I already know how to do in Command Prompt (version 6.3.9600).

In Command Prompt I can very easily type this (after the ">"):

```
Z:\input\convertToRinex.exe Z:\input\74390010.T01
```

And everything works perfectly. The .T01 file is converted and the resulting files appear in the input folder.

In Python I have no idea what I am doing. I've tried this:

```
from subprocess import *
call(['Z:\input\convertToRinex.exe', 'Z:\input\74390010.T01'])
```

And I get this error

```
Error: CtrimbleFile - unable to open file:Z:\psm_rinex\inputU90010.T01Open
```

In a window that says Z:\input\convertToRinex.exe at the top. It happens so fast that I had to use a screen recorder to read the error message.

I thought the list from Python would be translated into the exact same syntax that already works in Command Prompt and the same thing would happen.

I am clearly missing something. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "In Python I have no idea what I am doing." - A good start would be to read the [relevant documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) and learn the basics of the language, e.g. how strings work.

Comment: Never edit a question to include "fixed" or something similar. Use edits to add or correct information; fix grammatical or spelling errors, etc. SO is not a forum, I'd suggest you go read through the tour and the help center again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslashes have a special meaning inside strings in Python (and almost every other programming language) as [documented here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals), and so you need to write either

```
call(['Z:\\input\\convertToRinex.exe', 'Z:\\input\\74390010.T01'])
```

or

```
call([r'Z:\input\convertToRinex.exe', r'Z:\input\74390010.T01'])
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the `\`, use forward slashes or use raw string `r`:

```
'Z:\\input\\74390010.T01' # double \
'Z:/input/74390010.T01' # forward / 
r'Z:\input\74390010.T01' # raw string


In [7]: print('Z:\input\74390010.T01')
Z:\inputǣ90010.T01

In [8]: print(r'Z:\input\74390010.T01')
Z:\input\74390010.T01
```

`\` is used to [escape](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) characters